# Svelte: how to notify a child or sibling component

Tags: javascript, svelte

I know svelte is great for automatically updating components when some of its attributes change. But my scenario is slightly different. To simplify, let's say I have a parent Svelte component with two child components:

```html
<div>
  <child1 onButtonClicked={handleClick} />
  <child2 (1) />
</div>
<script>
  function handleClick() {
    (2)
  }
</script>
```

I want that when the user clicks a button inside `<child1>`, some function executes inside `<child2>`. What can I put in `(1)` and `(2)` to implement this behavior?

All I can think of is having a counter, incrementing it inside `handleClick` and pass the counter to `<child2>`, then use `$:` in `<child2>` to catch the change. But this would be a very contrived workaround. And of course I could move the code I want to execute from `<child2>` to the parent component, but that is even an uglier workaround, because `<child2>` is the one that really knows what to do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bind the function:

Child2.app

```
<script>
    .....
    export const someFunc = () => console.log('someFunc');
</script>

....
```

Your code update:

```
<script>
  import Child1 ... 
  import Child2 ...

  let child2;
  function handleClick() {
    child2.someFunc();
  }
</script>

<div>
  <Child1 onButtonClicked={handleClick} />
  <Child2 bind:this={child2} />
</div>
```

or:

```
<script>
  import Child1 ... 
  import Child2 ...

  let child2;
</script>

<div>
  <Child1 onButtonClicked={child2.someFunc} />
  <Child2 bind:this={child2} />
</div>
```

Repl: [Bind function to call this function from sibling component](https://svelte.dev/repl/8f405b556f9f4071bd5fea6051703466?version=3.35.0)

There are other ways to share a function between components. Like sharing a function between the parent and the child components using setContext and getContext;

Comment: Amazing, I didn't know that if I bind a component I get direct access to all its exported members.

Comment: After implementing it, I see that if the component hierarchy is complex (as is my case), then you end up passing events up and invocations down across all the hierarchy.
I assume that Redux-like techniques are the solution to avoid this kind of complexity, is that correct?

Comment: I'have never used redux. But you can use a reactive Svelte store to pass data around without hierarchy hassle.

Comment: The only problem I see with using a store is if Child2 will be used in more than one place, but with different data in each place.  If this is not the case, then a store isn't necessary either.  You can just `export const someFunc ...` in Child 2, then `import {someFunc} from `Child2.svelte` in the parent.

Voscausa's answer is the gold star if you specifically need the method from the component instance.